# Is the following homomorphism continuous?

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ be a closed, torsion-free and divisible subgroup of locally compact abelian group $X$ such that $nX=G$ for some $n$. For $x\in X$, there exist $g\in G$ such that $nx=ng$. So we can define a homomorphism $f:X\to G$, $f(x)=g$. Now, my question: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: In your second sentence, do you mean for all $g\in G$, there exists $x\in X$ such that $nx = g$? It seems that's what $nX = G$ implies, unless I've mixed something up.

Comment: It might also be helpful to note that $X = G\oplus H$, as $G$ is divisible and $X$ is abelian.

Comment: $G$ need not to split in $X$!

Comment: The map $\mu_n\colon G\to G$ defined by $\mu_n(g)=ng$ is a bijection, since $g$ is torsion-free divisible. So you're basically asking if $\mu_n^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: @aliakbar See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group#Properties)

Comment: @Stahl $G$ is an algebraically direct summand of $X$, no topologically direct summand.